# Constructing a rhombus $ABCD$ with $A$ a given point, $B$ on a given circle, and $C$ on a given line, such that $\angle A=60^\circ$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> Given a point $A$, a circle $b$ and a line $c$, construct a rhombus
> $ABCD$ such that $B \in b$, $C \in c$ and $ \measuredangle A = 60^\circ $.

Hello! I saw this geometry problem in a textbook and I tried to solve it, but I've made no progress so far. The thing is, I don't even know how to attack such a problem.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: @cosmo5 Don't you mean $ABD$?

Comment: Even when you don't even know how to attack such a problem, you can provide useful context. For instance: What kind and/or level of book is the source (textbook? olympiad practice book? etc). Also, what *exactly* have you tried in your own attempts? This information can help people tailor their responses to best serve you without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your (or the problem's intended) skill level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us observe a rhombus $ABCD$ with $\measuredangle A = 60^\circ.$ Its diagonal $AC$ has the length $|AC|=|AB|\sqrt 3,$ the angle at $A$ in $\triangle ABC$ is of measure $30^{\circ}.$

Therefore, $C$ is an image of $B$ in a transformation $$\sigma=\rho \circ \theta,$$
where the common center of the rotation $\rho$ and the homothety $\theta$ is $A,$ the angle of rotation is $30^{\circ}$ and a coefficient of homothety is $\sqrt 3.$
Then $C$ is an intersection point of $b$ and $\sigma(c).$

For further solutions, we can consider an oppositely oriented angle of rotation.

The enclosed picture shows one solution, a second point $C'$ is marked but the rhombus is not constructed.

[image]

Comment: Hi. How did you obtain B?

Comment: Once you have $C$ you can construct the perpendicular bisector of the segment $CA$ and the intersection with the circle will give you $B$.

Comment: considering bOOn het comment, then the given angle of A may not be equal to angle the joining the point of intersection of circle and perpendicular bisector of AC, that is there is no need for value of angle A .

Comment: @cosmo5 I obtained B by the inverse transformation of C.